# jQuery validation plugin - check if div exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am making a form and using [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

The user has to add at least 1 'tag' to the form before it can be validated. I add the 'tags' using a div.
This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            tags: {
                    required: function(element) {
                        return ($('.tag').length);
                    }
                },
            name: "required",
            "checkbox[]": "required",

        },
        messages: {
            tags: "No tags found",
            name: "input name!",
            "checkbox[]": "select at least 1 category",

        }
});

});
```

It gives the error even if the div exists sadly. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Resin

Comment: Please show the HTML that goes along with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I found a way to do it.

I just added an input to my div and refered to it instead, and also i changed

```
return ($('.tag').length);
```

to this

```
return $(".tag").length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Title:  jQuery validation plugin - check if div exist

It's not working because a `div` is not an `input` element.  [Please see the documentation for full proper usage](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).